# Rails DB Rake Tasks Not Running After Deleting Migration File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I deleted a migration file I didnt need anymore (deleted, not rollback). Then tried to run migrations and my rake tasks stopped doing anything altogether. What ended up fixing my problem (or so I thought) was adding another migration which ended up working for running rake db:migrate for the latest migration. Then after the latest schema was set my rake tasks stopped working again altogether.

I am using rails 5. I tried using the new rails command for db tasks, but that didnt work.

I know I'm not showing code here, but its kind of difficult for this problem. I included a screenshot of what happens when I run tasks for my app. Youll see various ruby warnings because I should upgrade my version, but those are not related.

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem before or have any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this before, We don't have enough information to give a perfect answer, so I have given you a few suggestions that have worked for me.

before you try anything drastic, run `rails db:reset`.

Hopefully that works, if not hopefully you are using git or svn. Go back to when it worked, then don't delete the migration file. Create a new migration that drops the table you don't need anymore.

to do this run 'rails g migration drop_TABLE_NAME' that will make a new migration file, you can drop a table like this below.

```
def change
 drop_table :TABLENAME
end
```

If you aren't using git, I would try editing `db/schema.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I had my database in my db.yml set to default. I had to declare actual database names and then run migrations in order to get it to work.

For me my db.yml now looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template0
  database: job-board-development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

While previously it looked like this:

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  template: template0
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000